# Cygwin creating multiple links to files inside tar?

Tags: cygwin, tar, 7-zip

I'm trying to create a .tar file in Cygwin:

```
find . > tmpfilelist
tar -cf tmp.tar -T tmpfilelist
```

but when I open *tmp.tar* in Windows with 7-Zip there are four instances of each file:

```
Name              Size            Link
.gitignore        62
.gitignore        0               path/to/.gitignore
.gitignore        0               path/to/.gitignore
.gitignore        0               path/to/.gitignore
```

and when I extract the tar to its own folder I am prompted to overwrite each file three times. Additionally, viewing the extracted folder's properties in Explorer shows a size of 0 bytes.

Is it possible to create a .tar file in Cygwin that will behave in Windows? Just to clarify, I'm only using the *.gitignore* files as an example; the issue seems to be with all files.

Edit:

```
$ tar -tvf tmp.tar | grep -i "link to" | grep -i ".gitignore" | sort | head -n20
hrw-r--r-- user/None        0 2011-07-06 11:27 path/to/.gitignore link to path/to/.gitignore
hrw-r--r-- user/None        0 2011-07-06 11:27 path/to/.gitignore link to path/to/.gitignore
hrw-r--r-- user/None        0 2011-07-06 11:27 path/to/.gitignore link to path/to/.gitignore
hrw-r--r-- user/None        0 2011-09-29 15:40 path/to/other/.gitignore link to path/to/other/.gitignore
hrw-r--r-- user/None        0 2011-09-29 15:40 path/to/other/.gitignore link to path/to/other/.gitignore
hrw-r--r-- user/None        0 2011-09-29 15:40 path/to/other/.gitignore link to path/to/other/.gitignore
...
```

.

```
$ grep -i ".gitignore" tmpfilelist | sort | head -n20
path/to/.gitignore
path/to/other/.gitignore
...
```

Cygwin's `tar` is showing the same listing, but the *tmpfilelist* does not appear to have these extra links. So I guess the real question is how to make a nicely formed tar file in Cygwin? I'm not sure if they're relevant or how to apply `tar`'s `--dereference` and `--hard-dereference` options.

Edit: As far as I know, `7z` doesn't preserve directory structures when given a list of files without specifying a root and there is no common root for some of the files in my list (the list will eventually be aggregate for multiple `find` executions).

Comment: Have you tried 7zip? [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) allows you to double click the file inside its file manager and explore it, so you can double click the tar.bz and get the tar, and double click again to get the files inside.

Comment: @AlanTuring: I'm not creating a `tar.bz`, I'm only using `tar -cf`.

Comment: What do you get if your execute `tar -tvf tmp.tar`?  Also, what is listed if you print out file tmpfilelist?

Comment: pretty sure 7zip has support for every archive under the sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem may be that `find . > tmpfilelist` lists both files and directories.

`tar` parses `tmpfilelist` and adds any listed directory to the tar file **with its contents**.

`tar` also adds any file listed in `tmpfilelist`, but those files **were already added** by `tar` when it processed the directories. The result is that files are included more than once (eventually many times, if files reside deep in the directory structure).

You should use:

`find . ! -type d > tmpfilelist`

to generate a list of filesystem objects with the exception of directories.

As for the symlinks you mention, it's a mistery to me how they end up being part of the tar file.

EDIT:
The symlinks may already exist. List them with `find . -type l`.

Comment: Excluding directories in the `find` seems to have solved all my problems. I didn't realize `tar` had that particular behavior. Thanks!